# Does this integral actually vanish?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, dirac-equation

When doing P&S Exercise 3.4 (e), I stumbled upon the following Hamiltonian:

$$H = \frac{1}{2}\int d^3p\xi^{rT}p\sigma\xi^{s}(a^{r\dagger}_pa^s_p+a^{s\dagger}_pa^r_p),$$

where $\xi^{1,2} = (1,0)^T,(0,1)^T$ are spinors, and $p\sigma = p_\mu\sigma^\mu$ with $\sigma^\mu = (1,\sigma^i)$ and $\sigma^i$ the Pauli matrices. Expanding $H$ into time and space parts gives two expressions, with the time component reducing to the correct Hamiltonian:

$$H = \int d^3pa^{s\dagger}_pa^{s}_p.$$

So now I feel like the space part

$$\int d^3 p\xi^{r T} \mathbf{p}\mathbf{\sigma}\xi^s (a^{r\dagger}_{p} a^s_{p} + a^{s\dagger}_{p} a^r_{p}) \equiv \int d^3 p\xi^{r T} \mathbf{p}\mathbf{\sigma}\xi^s A(\mathbf{p})$$

should vanish, not only because that would give the correct Hamiltonian but also because *it seems* to be odd in $\mathbf{p}$. But doing a change of variable leads to

$$-\int d^3 p\xi^{r T} \mathbf{p}\mathbf{\sigma}\xi^s (a^{r\dagger}_{-p} a^s_{-p} + a^{s\dagger}_{-p} a^r_{-p}) = -\int d^3 p\xi^{r T} \mathbf{p}\mathbf{\sigma}\xi^s A(-\mathbf{p}).$$

(The notation is a bit sloppy but when I say $a_p$, I mean the spatial momentum $\mathbf{p}$ and thus $a_{-p}$ is now a function of ($E_\mathbf{p},-\mathbf{p})$.)

I have been trying to prove that $A(\mathbf{p})=A(-\mathbf{p})$ or that $A(\mathbf{p})$ doesn't actually depend on $\mathbf{p}$ but to no avail. Am I on the right track here? Is $A(\mathbf{p})=A(-\mathbf{p})$ or have I made a mistake somewhere along the line?

To add a bit of context, the exercise wants me to construct a diagonalized Hamiltonian for Majorana particles obeying the usual anticommutation relations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are creation and annihilation operators functions of momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/791579/)

Comment: @hft Not really. In your answer you said that it depends on the commutation relations but I am struggling to make a connection between the anticommutation relations and $A(p)$. These are two different expressions and $A(p)$ has so far refused to be written in terms of the anticommutation relations. I feel like knowing the commutation relations does not help me in this case.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you understand the anti-commutation relations to be? Isn't the part in parenthesis on the LHS of the third equation you wrote a trivial function of $\vec p$?

Comment: (I mean your $A(\vec p)$ appears to just be $\delta^{rs})$

Comment: $\{a^{r\dagger}_p,a^{s}_q \} = \delta^{rs}\delta(p-q)$ and in our case where $p = q$, this reduces to an expression constant in $p$ - $\delta^{rs}\delta(0)$ which makes the anticommutator momentum-independent. However, $A(\mathbf{p})$ is NOT the anticommutator because in the second term there is an $a^{s\dagger}$.

Comment: @hft Also regarding that question: while I did get the answer to that question (and also learned something new) it turns out that that was the wrong question. Which is why I asked this one after some more exploration :)

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Another clarifying question. Is the thing you wrote as $\vec p \sigma$ supposed to be a dot product between $\vec p$ and $\sigma$: $\sum_i p_i \sigma^i$? Or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, it's a dot product. Essentially, I have split $p\sigma = p^0\sigma^0 +p_i\sigma^i$, where the second term is a sum over $i$.